# How to make a subproject produce a ZIP artifact

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a projectA that produces an AAR and added a task that makes a jar. I have another projectB that depends on projectA jar.

I don't know how to make it work. I get this error:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find ProjectA-shared.jar (project :ProjectA).
```

**ProjectA**:

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'ProjectA'
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
group "com.projecta"

...


task clientJar(type: Jar) {
    from "$buildDir/intermediates/javac/release/compileReleaseJavaWithJavac/classes"
    //some filter here
    appendix "shared"
    classifier 'shared'
}
```

**ProjectB**:

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'ProjectB'

if (new File(rootDir, '../ProjectA').exists()) {
    includeBuild '../ProjectA'
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation "com.projecta:ProjectA:1.0:shared@jar"
}
```

I want when I run the build of projectB to retreive correctly the JAR.

Comment: Is name of jar file 'ProjectA-shared.jar'?

Comment: Yes it is 'ProjectA-shared.jar.